# In PyCharm, without admin rights, I can’t select an interpreter in wsl2

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After reinstalling Windows 10, I reinstalled wsl2, Ubuntu and Docker Desktop. Everything is working. I installed PyCharm Professional, but I can’t configure the Python interpreter running in Ubuntu, that is, via wsl. The system interpreter writes that it can only be installed with admin rights. Visible on the screenshot. A virtual interpreter can also be created only as an administrator. If I create virtual interpreter without admin rights, I get a Java error: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.jpountz.xxhash.XXHashJNI". Although the path to Java is prescribed in Windows. Java rights have been expanded for all users. And with admin rights there is no such problem.
If I create an interpreter with admin rights, then the installed Python packages are visible and it is possible to work with/delete/add them. But if I then re-login as a regular user, this opportunity disappears.
If I create any interpreter (system or virtual) without admin rights, I will first get an error about accessing Ubuntu. Look at the screenshot.
[image]

Here is the requirement: admin rights
[image]

Here is a screenshot if I try to set up a virtual environment without first setting up the system interpreter. That is, I get an access denial: "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot unpack liblz4-java: java.io.IOException: Access denied"
[image]

How to configure PyCharm so that the Python interpreter is installed not only under admin rights?

P.S. I decided to add another screenshot to show that I select a virtual environment using PyCharm and what error I get
[image]

I would also like to emphasize that there is no such situation in the answers offered to me. I can create a virtual environment in Ubuntu and then register it in PyCharm, but this is inconvenient and I did not need to do this before. Everything was done right away in PyCharm.

The proposed option to install packages in a virtual environment via pip also does not work, and I initially emphasized that this function is not active if I run PyCharm as a regular user.
[image]

I'm not saying this is a PyCharma problem, maybe it's a system problem. But where is it and how to fix it. Moreover, this is not observed with other programs.

Comment: Permissions to _install packages_ is not the same as permissions to _select_ an interpreter that's already installed, or to install something in your home directory (as several supplemental package-management systems are capable of). This isn't a pycharm thing, it's an operating-system thing.

Comment: Anyhow, it's recommending that you create a virtualenv and select that virtualenv's interpreter, and that's good advice. `python -m venv ~/myproject.venv` for example will create a `~/myproject.venv/bin/python` that you can point pycharm at, and which you don't need admin privileges to install dependencies for. (Indeed, look on the left and you'll see a "Virtualenv Environment" option -- you can and should use that instead of "System Interpreter").

Comment: Apparently my desire to write briefly is to blame. I wrote that I was trying to install a virtual environment without admin rights and was getting a Java error. And the method suggested by @Charles Duffy works on Ubuntu without PyCharm.
But why make unnecessary gestures if the virtual environment must be configured in PyCharm and there is a corresponding button for this, which is visible in my screenshot just above the system interpreter.
I didn't have this problem before reinstalling Windows. Both interpreters were configured in PyCharm. Also, I'm not saying this is a PyCharm problem

Comment: Try reinstalling PyCharm, your own installation of Java shouldn't really matter unless you've configured PyCharm to use it because Java is usually bundled with PyCharm.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Unfortunately, reinstalling PyCharm did not help.

Comment: The "Target Creation Error" part is a PyCharm problem rather than a system problem, so that's an aspect JetBrains customer support should be able to help with.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem myself. In short, there are two reasons:

1. It was necessary to install the jdk, but I only installed the jre from Java.
2. The most important reason. All the same, access rights are to blame. I didn't even think about it right away. But I have an SSD system drive. To wear it out less, I always set up the Temp directory on drive D. But on the old Windows it was already created. And some programs on the new Windows write their temporary files there. And although I registered the path to it on the new system, I did not check the rights and did not increase them. Although Java writes that it cannot unpack its package, which is what I showed on the screenshot in my question. After I raised the permissions for the Temp directory, everything worked.